# Merge 3 tables in one table

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 3 tables (t1, t2, t3) in postgresql. they all have same number of columns (**168** cols) with same type and overall **300k** rows.

How can I add all of them in one table?

Comment: **168** columns? That sounds like you have the wrong datamodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into t4
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2
union all
select * from t3
```

or, if you want to create table during select:

```
select * into t4 from t1
union all
select * from t2
union all
select * from t3;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/50652/1)